# Using relative path in QGIS 3.x processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I try to use a relative path for the algorithm "Set style for vector layer" in the processing modeler, but it works only with absolute path.

A similar request is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278047/how-to-use-a-relative-path-in-qgis-3-0-processing-modeler?rq=1), but the answer doesn't suit me. It is proposed to copy the files to the root of the hard drive. I need to share the model and the qlm files with external users who may not have access to the root of the disk or whose disk is not named c: /  and aren't on the same network.

Would someone have a other solution?

Comment: Why does the answer at the duplicate not suit you?  If you are seeking additional answers to that question then you could consider placing a bounty on it.  See https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010/options-when-question-is-duplicate-of-one-with-no-inadequate-old-answers for that and other options which do not include asking the same question again (which creates a duplicate).